# Delphi custom button accel key

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm coding a custom button derived from tExCustomControl wich, in turn, is derived from tCustomControl. The tExCustomControl component, takes care of painting and showing the caption. I managed to display the caption with the accel char underlined, using WinAPI. How I can tell Windows that the accel key is associated with the tExButton, so it can handle the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell Windows anything.  When the user types an accelerator, Windows sends your app a [`WM_SYSCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646357.aspx) message, which the VCL handles automatically.  As the VCL searches for which control handles the accelerator, your component will receive a `CM_DIALOGCHAR` message, which you need to respond to, eg:

```
type
  TMyCustomButton = class(tExCustomControl)
  private
    procedure CMDialogChar(var Message: TCMDialogChar); message CM_DIALOGCHAR;
  end;

procedure TMyCustomButton.CMDialogChar(var Message: TCMDialogChar);
begin
  if IsAccel(Message.CharCode, Caption) and Enabled and Visible and
    (Parent <> nil) and Parent.Showing then
  begin
    Click;
    Result := 1;
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

`IsAccel()` is a public function in the `Vcl.Forms` unit:

```
function IsAccel(VK: Word; const Str: string): Boolean;
```

It parses an accelerator from the provided `Str` value and compares it to the provided `VK` value.

The code above is exactly how `TSpeedButton` implements accelerators, for instance.

Comment: This I already had achieved handling the KeyUp event. The thing is that if there are more than one tExCustomControls, Windows sends the message to the first of the kind that was placed on the form. What I need is making Windows understand that that particular accel key must be handled by a determined tExCustomControl. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: when I say "tell Windows" I say it figuratively. I'm aware of the Windows message system.

Comment: Correction: what I need is making the VCL understand that that particular accel key must be handled by a determined tExCustomControl (or something of the kind). Thanks. (Forgive me I'm saying nonsense).

Comment: You are missing the point.  DO NOT implement an accelerator using `Key...` events.  The VCL pre-processes accelerator keystrokes and generates a `CM_DIALOGCHAR` message accordingly.  The VCL broadcasts the message to child controls, menus, and action lists until one of them responds with a matching accelerator.  As long as your controls each have a unique accelerator, only one should ever be responding to the message. If multiple controls have the same accelerator, then of course it is going to be a first-come-first-serve scenario in which one ends up processing the message.

Comment: You hit the jackpot! In fact, in the constructor i set the caption to '&Caption' and that was the problem since this is the default caption for all tExCustomControls. I didn't recall about this particular setting. All I have to do, is remove the '&' char from the default caption. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remy is quite right (+1), and I must stress again what he says about handling `Key...` events. Not appropriate for accelerators. And as I told you at your previous question, `KeyUp` would be the wrong one in any case. Accelerators are actioned when the key goes down.

Comment: Yes you were right. I apologize. Now the whole thing is working just fine. Thanks...